Is it possible to bounding an operator's norm from its action on orthogonal complements more tightly than with the triangle inequality?
Consider a Hilbert space with subspace $M$ and its orthogonal complement $N$.  Let $B$ denote a bounded linear operator on the Hilbert space.  The projection operators $P_M$ and $P_N$ project onto the orthogonal subspaces.
Therefore, the norm of the operator $B$ on the $M$ subspace is $\|B P_M\|$ and similarly, the norm of the operator $B$ on the $N$ subspace is $\|B P_N\|$.
In general, is it possible to bound $\|B\|$ from these components more tightly than by $\|B\|\leq \|B P_M\| + \|B P_N\|$?

Yes. We have,
$$\begin{split}
\|Bh\| &\leq \|BP_Mh\| + \|BP_Nh\|\\
&\leq \|BP_M\|\|P_Mh\| + \|BP_N\|\|P_Nh\|\\
&\leq (\|BP_M\|^2 + \|BP_N\|^2)^{1/2}(\|P_Mh\|^2 + \|P_Nh\|^2)^{1/2}\\
&= (\|BP_M\|^2 + \|BP_N\|^2)^{1/2}\|h\|
\end{split}$$
So $\|B\| \leq (\|BP_M\|^2 + \|BP_N\|^2)^{1/2}$. This is the tightest possible without any assumption on the ranges of $BP_M$ and $BP_N$. For example, it can happen that $B$ maps a unit vector $u$ in $M$ to some unit vector $\xi$ in $H$, and maps a unit vector $v$ in $N$ also to $\xi$. Moreover, $\|BP_M\| = \|BP_N\| = 1$. Then $B(u + v) = 2\xi$, $\|u + v\| = \sqrt{2}$, so $\|B\| \geq \sqrt{2}$. And the bound $(\|BP_M\|^2 + \|BP_N\|^2)^{1/2}$ is also $\sqrt{2}$ in this case.

If the ranges of $BP_M$ and $BP_N$ happen to be orthogonal, then a tighter bound, $|B| \leq \max{|BP_M|, |BP_N|}$, is possible. (In fact, $|B|$ will exactly equal the RHS.) But this does need assumptions on the ranges of $BP_M$ and $BP_N$.
